# What is a convenient way of nesting routes in ASP.NET Core (previously ASP.NET 5)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, asp.net-core

We want to have nested routes, since we have a hierarchical structure of data.
However, the intuitive way of doing this is have one master controller that controls everything. Of course we don't want that. We want nicely contained controllers that are units (following OO principles).

For example, we have an API call like this:

```
http://domain.com/api/customers/3510/status/
```

We want to have a nice status controller, which will have a set of actions to deliver information related to status.

I have figured out a way to do this as follows:

```
[Route("api/customers/{aId:int}/status")]
public class StatusController
{
   [HttpGet("current")]
   public string GetCurrentStatus(int aId)
   {
     return "Status customer " + aId + " is foo bar". 
   }
}
```

But is this the right way to do this? Or are there other ways to do this more convenient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route `[Route("api/customers/{aId:int}/status")]` looks ok to me.

Tho the convention in MVC 6 seems to be to return an `IActionResult`:

```
   [HttpGet("current")]
   public IActionResult GetCurrentStatus(int aId)
   {
     return Content("Status customer " + aId + " is foo bar"); 
   }
```

Comment: The IActionResult is most of the time only when using it in a WebApplication, in a WebApi, you can return anything you want. Most of the time it will be converted to JSON/XML/etc.

Answer (score 1):

One potential option would be to use [MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/), which allows you to nest your controllers into a hierarchy and the routes will automatically follow accordingly (according to the namespace the controllers are in).

Unfortunately, at this stage there is no support for MVC Core, but you could potentially reverse engineer it and create an upgraded version (and preferably make a contribution to the project, so the rest of us can benefit from the upgrade).